# can we use SOAP on intranet?

Tags: web-services, soap, webservice-client

I am new to services. I am sorry for my question being a little theoretical. On a site I was reading about SOAP, they said it works over internet.

Can we use SOAP based services in intranet environment ?

Can we use HTTP over intranet or it is just a internet protocol ?

Please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SOAP over any TCP network. This could be internet or intranet. SOAP is an interoperable protocol over HTTP. And HTTP works over TCP. So everywhere you have HTTP you can have SOAP. Basically SOAP is a protocol which allows for heterogeneous systems to communicate using an industry defined standards.

And note that SOAP is getting less attention lately compared to [REST](http://www.slideshare.net/kjbuckley/doing-rest-right-3385800) which is starting to gain lots of momentum.

Comment: *Why* you would want to start a new web service using SOAP is another question entirely, and best directed to a local psychiatrist.

Comment: :)

Thanks David Ellis, but you did not tell what is its alternate ?

Comment: @haansi: It depends on your requirements (there are a minority of cases that SOAP makes sense -- usually compatibility with an already implemented, proprietary system that can handle SOAP), but the general trend has been the realization that over-the-wire bandwidth is precious, and you need validation logic on both ends, *anyway*, so a JSON-based REST API for your web service is in vogue because they are simple to understand and lightweight for a text-based serialization format.

Comment: @haansi: Just to iterate a bit more, for web services there's a hierarchy from lightweight to heavyweight, where the lighter it is the easier to debug problems, but the more "scaffolding" you write yourself, while the heavier weight can get you up-and-running faster, but good luck debugging corner-cases (that could involve different vendors' implementations of the standard). Basically, JSON REST < JSON-RPC < XML-RPC < SOAP (in terms of "weight").

Answer (score 1):

SOAP is a service supported by a server/web service. You can even use SOAP to translate data between two services on the same server box that have no other form of API.